# error ! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra } while using table environment

Tags: tables, errors

I have one mainfile thesis:

`\documentclass{report}`

In this file I load a package for the set up, made by my University. 
I also load other standard packages.

Furthermore I load a subfile called chptr1 in the mainfile thesis with the following command:

```
\input{chptr1}
```

In the subfile chptr1 I have a chaptertitle, a few sections and a paragraph with this table in it:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}

This is chapter 1

\section{Section 1}

This is section 1
\begin{itemize}
\item
... 
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Subsection 1}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection 1}

\paragraph{Paragraph 1}

This is Paragraph 1

\begin{itemize}
\item
...
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[t] 

  \begin{center} 

   \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|} % error occurs here!

       A & B & C & D  \\
       \hline
       1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
       \hline  
   \end{tabular}

  \end{center}

\caption{This is the Caption for Table 1}

\end{table}

This is equation \ref{eqtn: 1}. 

\begin{equation}
\label{eqtn: 1}
\end {equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item
...
\end{itemize}

\paragrpah{Paragraph 2}

This is paragraph 2
```

So when use this code to set up a table in a paragraph I always get the following errors:

> - ! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }

```
! Argument of \@firstoftwo has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.50 \begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
```

> - ! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.

```
! Paragraph ended before \@firstoftwo was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.50 \begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

> - ! Argument of \reserved@b has an extra }.

```
! Argument of \reserved@b has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.50 \begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|}
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.  
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
Runaway argument?
{\@xtabularcr }\futurelet \@let@token \@ifnch \\ Zonder voorafgaande \ETC.
```

> - ! Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.

```
! Paragraph ended before \reserved@b was complete.
<to be read again>
\par
l.50 \begin{tabular} {|c|c|c|c|}
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
)
```

> - ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50. \fi\input{hfdst2}

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50.
<inserted text>
\fi
l.95 \input{hfdst2}
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.
)
```

> - ! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 24. \fi<>thesis.tex

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 50.
<inserted text>
\fi
<*> thesis.tex
The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.
```

These errors are refer to the indicated line in the code.

I've also tried to copy paste the table to the mainfile, but still the same errors appear. So I think the problem is not necessarily directly connected to the code?

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid I am unable to generate an error message from running your code in a simple LaTeX environment. There must be some packages, or some other macros, that have been enabled and that are contributing to the error. Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001) that generates the error(s) you are encountering.

Comment: I'm afraid that the indicated line in your code is not causing any error.

Comment: Thanks for providing some additional information. Unfortuntately, it's still not enough to help pin-point the source of the error. For sure, the code snippet you've posted so far cannot be the cause, or causes, of the error. LaTeX error message can be confusing and cryptic at times, as they often show up not immediately when the erroneous code occurs but later on, when something else triggers an exception. Please post the paragraph or two that precedes the table.

Comment: You should show the full error message from the log from `!` to `?` in a `{}` code section so line endings are preserved (tex error messages are multi-line and the linebreaks are important as they show what tex was reading at the time) you have only shown an abbreviated form, probably from spme editor view. Also it clearly shows `\fi\input{chptr2}` so you have some conditional code (`\fi` in your main file, which you have not shown)

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce your errors with the code you provide. The only error it throws is `! Undefined control sequence. \paragrpah`

Comment: [How to prepare a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) gives you all you need to give us all we need to answer your question.